# F# compilation error related to inheritance

Tags: inheritance, compilation, f#

I have 2 interfaces defined in a C# component, where 1 interface inherits from another generic interface

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
void Add(T obj);
void Update(T obj);
void Delete(T obj);
}
public interface IDataModelRepository :
    IRepository<DataModel>
{
}
```

I have an F# component where I define a generic type with a constructor parameter with the generic interface:

```
type Domain<T> ( getRepository:System.Func<IRepository<T>>) = ...
```

Then I define a derived type using the derived interface:

```
type DataModelDomain ( getRepository:System.Func<IDataModelRepository>) =
inherit Domain<DataModel> (getRepository)
```

This does not compile giving the error message on the DataModelDomain type:

> The type 'IRepository' does not match the type 'IDataModelRepository'

However if I define those 'Domain' types in classes in a C# component in a similar way, it does compile. Is there a way to define the DataModelDomain type deriving from the generic Domain type and using the derived interface IDataModelRepository

Comment: Have you tried: `inherit Domain<DataModel> (getRepository :> IRepository)` ?

Comment: Yes I did. It displayes another error message: The type 'System.Func<IRepository<DataModel>>' does not have any subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coersion

Comment: I see. Why are you using `System.Func<...>` and not simply `(getRepository: IRepository<T>)`?

Comment: The application is a desktop app. The domain instances are singletons and are created at startup time. The app is now architected in such a way that every call from the UI to a domain creates a new instance of a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to reproduce the problem in compiling F# code. And then fixed it by creating a new function, calling the other one inside it, and safely upcasting the result: `(fun () -> getRepository.Invoke() :> IRepository<DataModel>)`

Here's the whole thing:

```
type DataModel = DataModel

type IRepository<'T> =
    abstract member Add: 'T -> unit
    abstract member Update : 'T -> unit
    abstract member Delete : 'T -> unit

type IDataModelRepository =
    inherit IRepository<DataModel>

type Domain<'T> ( getRepository:System.Func<IRepository<'T>>) =
    do ()

type DataModelDomain ( getRepository:System.Func<IDataModelRepository>) =
    inherit Domain<DataModel> (fun () -> getRepository.Invoke() :> IRepository<DataModel>)
    do ()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was already looking in this direction, but I was missing the 'Invoke()' part. I don't know exactly why this works and not just 'getRepository()', but that is my limited knowledge of F#

Comment: If this was all F# code you wouldn't use a `Func`, you would use an F# function: `unit -> IRespository<'T>`, and then you wouldn't need to use `Invoke()`. `Func` is a .NET thing which has to be used a little bit differently from F#. In fact, if these classes are intended for use in F# then switch to using F# functions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case the 'repository layer' is a C# component. The reason is that I use EFCore with migrations. And as far as I know migrations are not supported in F#.